# Flask Templating Language Not Displaying Properly

Tags: python, flask

My flask template is not displaying properly. For some reason, the templating language is being displayed on the webpage.

Here is what it looks like (red circles indicate items that should not be on the web page)

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. The templates are stored in a folder called `static` and in my `app.py`, I have the following line as well:

`app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='static')`

Edit: Here is the code that renders the following portion of this page:

`

```
                  {% if passphrase %}
                    <div>
                      <h4>Information</h4>
                      <p>Address: 123_easy_uncover_street</p>
                    </div>
                  {% else %}
                    <div class="col">
                      <h4>Enter passphrase</h4>
                      <form action="" method="POST" style="text-align:left">
                          <label for="passphrase">Passphrase</label>
                          <input type="text" id="passphrase" name="passphrase">
                          <br>
                          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                      </form>
                    </div>

                    <div id="status" class="col" >
                      <p><i>Please enter your passphrase</i></p>
                    </div>
                  {% endif %}
                  
                </div>`
```

Flask code:

```
from app.bank_database import BankDatabase
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import random
import json

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='static')
db = BankDatabase()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", passphrase="")


@app.route('/check_passphrase', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def check_passphrase():
    passphrase = request.args.get("passphrase")

    
    if db.check_passphrase(passphrase):
        #Show address here
        #TODO - change view to show passphrase
        return render_template("index.html", passphrase=passphrase)
    
    return render_template("index.html", passphrase="")

app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: Show us the code that renders this page.

Comment: Added @TimRoberts

Comment: No, I meant show us the Python code that calls the Flask template handler.

Comment: Got it, added @TimRoberts

Comment: And the Flask code you show is actually inside `index.html`?  You haven't done something clever like an <iframe>?